# Why is the output of this class AB amplifier not equal to Vsine?

Tags: class-ab

I'm simulating a class AB power amplifier.

According to the theory that I learned, the voltage at C8(2) should be equal to C10(1.) Why is there a huge gap between them (5.83 vs 1.89?)

The input impedance of this circuit is an approximation with R10 = R11. Is that correct?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can the reader visualize this big gap. I looked at the oscilloscope and didn't recognize the numbers you talk about. I'd be more concerned about the clipping.

Comment: I highlight 3 voltage at C10(1), C8(2), D2(A). That is not right way to see gap ?

Comment: If you can see the gap in your image that's fine but, I have no idea what the scales are nor where this gap is that you refer to.

Comment: @ErnestoG I think that at one time, just one BJT is work, and the other is cut-off.

Comment: @Southgoodman that's valid at the peaks of a sine wave (and somewhere before them too), but at DC they should be holding a valid DC point. Is 16V the middle of your supply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see Q9's Vbe is reverse biased, the emitter is at a higher voltage than the base. It won't work.

You have to put some effort to bias the bases. I have no idea what your VCC value is, but the fact that D1 is reversed biased as well means this isn't properly biased. Perhaps you're not allowing enough current to flow through the diodes?

Comment: Vcc is 30V. Oh, D1 is really in trouble. I change R10, and R11 to 50 Ohm, and the two wave is the same. Thank you. But look like finding a 50Ohm is not realistic when I make the PCB.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GwG2r1P

Comment: @Southgoodman why don't you make a proper current source instead of a resistor, then?

Comment: Ah, My teacher permits me to use only Vcc = 30V and Ground, and no more voltage or current source.

Comment: @Southgoodman there exists 49.9 ohm standard resistors.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you for that help. Can I ask you another question, when Resistor is 50 ohm, there is some problem the input impedance is too low (50 ohm), and the wasting power on R10, R11, and Diode is a concern. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Southgoodman to comply with site's etiquette, you could ask another question in this forum or you could send me an email (check my profile). As the other answerer said, you need a driver transistor to provide the high input impedance.

Comment: @ErnestoG 30V over 100ohms make for 9 Watts of power burnt off in the resistors.  That is likely to add a lot of thermal noise and likely quite a bit of smell...

Comment: @user107063 I constrained myself to solve the biasing issue.I didn't pay attention to that, but yes, you're right (tho is about ~15V) are dropped across the resistors. There are much better ways to do this, but the question was already set as a XY problem, looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Typical current gain of a TIP41/TIP42 is 75, and you produce the base current for an 8ohm load through 2k resistors at a voltage amplification of 1.

You are missing a driver transistor stage to make this work.  A Sziklai pair configuration does not raise the biasing voltage requirements, a Darlington pair adds another diode forward voltage to the biasing.

Comment: Can I use Common Collector configuration instead of Darlington Pair ?

Comment: @Southgoodman Huh?  You already _have_ both transistors of your push-pull pair in Common Collector configuration.  And _cascading_ two transistors in Common Collector configuration _is_ a Darlington pair.

Comment: @Southgoodman your question has morphed from why doesn't my buffer work to a full design with specifications, apparently. Why don't you change your question into the core of the problem and not starting with "why is my solution failing".

Comment: @ErnestoG "This is not a site for getting your homework done."  Posting a whole spec will invariably lead to "show your work so far", and that's exactly what has been done here.  Yes, this will likely lead to followup questions instead of getting everything done by someone else at once.  This is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: @user107063 the original question was very limited. If he extends it to what was needed AND his solution would be much better than showing only his solution and asking why it doesn't work.